# How to tell if an Installer (InstallShield specifically) completes successfully?

Tags: c#, installation, installshield

I am starting an installer from my application and then synchronously waiting for it to complete.

```
Process installerProcess = Process.Start("TheProcessName");

// Must EnableRaisingEvents before calling synchronous method WaitForExit 
// according to MSDN documentation.
installerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

installerProcess.WaitForExit();
```

My application needs to know if this installer completed successfully or not. If the user cancelled it or it failed for any reason, I need to find out.

I tried the `ExitCode` property of the process thinking that '0' would signify success and all other codes would signify failure but it showed the same exit code for a successful or unsuccessful install so now I am stumped. Any ideas? Or is there a better way of doing this than I am currently doing it?

Comment: You are doing the right thing.  Obviously InstallShield is not.

Comment: That's what I'm starting to think. Just thought I might have been missing something. I'll find out if I can get the installer created with standard exit codes. I'll give this another couple of hours before closing it - just in case there's an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the approach Windows uses for checking installer compatibility is to watch the number of keys under the [Uninstall registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105(VS.85).aspx). If this increases, chances are good that the install was a success. In your case you could probably look for just any relevant registry key installed by the particular installer you launch, but its uninstall key could be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's an interesting approach. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

What type of InstallShield project are you using?  MSI or script driven?  I've always had msixec and setup.exe return meaningful exit codes.  Something is not right here.